# Google Maps view integrated with FBLitho

Tags: java, android, litho

I am trying to integrate a Google Maps View with Litho, and I have created a MountSpec for this. I have two issues with this.

Firstly, I need to run some background thread code in the OnPrepare Method, but as a result, I cannot assign the result of the background task to the Output object. What is a better way to handle this?

Secondly, when the view renders, it throws an error (Stacktrace below).

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.location.places.internal.zzas cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout$OnRefreshListener
>                                                                                at com.facebook.litho.widget.Recycler.onPrepare(Recycler.java:98)
>                                                                                at com.facebook.litho.ComponentLifecycle.createLayout(ComponentLifecycle.java:251)
>                                                                                at com.facebook.litho.LayoutState.createTree(LayoutState.java:1237)
>                                                                                at com.facebook.litho.LayoutState.createAndMeasureTreeForComponent(LayoutState.java:1406)
>                                                                                at com.facebook.litho.LayoutState.calculate(LayoutState.java:928)
>                                                                                at com.facebook.litho.ComponentTree.calculateLayoutState(ComponentTree.java:1235)
>                                                                                at com.facebook.litho.ComponentTree.measure(ComponentTree.java:545)
>                                                                                at com.facebook.litho.LithoView.onMeasure(LithoView.java:218)
>                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
>                                                                                at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1658)
>                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
>                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5608)
>                                                                                at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
>                                                                                at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
>                                                                                at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1391)
>                                                                                at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:784)
>                                                                                at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
>                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5608)
>                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)

This is the MountSpec that is throwing the error:

```
mapView.getMapAsync(googleMap -> {
            Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(googleApiClient, locationId)
                    .setResultCallback(places -> {
                        googleMap.addMarker(
                                new MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(new LatLng(0,0))
                        );
                        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                    });
        });
```